# Redrawing a control at design time when a property is changed

Tags: .net

I've got a .NET (specifically C#) control which is a subclass of a RadioButton, and has an extra property to add a second text string to it. In fact, exactly what the property does isn't important - the important thing is that it should change the appearance of the control.

On changing this property in design view and pressing enter, the control on the form designer doesn't change. If I change a property which was already present on the RadioButton, the control redraws itself with the new text. I think this is probably achieved through a IDesigner type or an attribute, but I can't find out what.

How do I make the control redraw on changing my added property?

Comment: Is this any help?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316193/question-how-to-invalidate-refresh-the-vs-ide-designer-for-c

Comment: Or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336346/how-to-refresh-a-winform-custom-control-at-design-time-after-changing-a-property

Comment: @Gareth Calling Invalidate() at the end of the setter works (as per the second link). It just seems an unnecessary (albeit tiny) overhead as it will do the same at runtime. Any thoughts on a design-time only option?

Comment: Use Component.DesignMode to determine whether to execute the code? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component.designmode.aspx

Comment: @Gareth Yes, that works too. Just downloaded and had a look at the .NET source and they use Invalidate() in there too, so I'll stick with that.

Answer (score 4):

Probably most people won't read the comments, so I'll post it as an answer.

Let me explain it with a very simple example:

```
public override Color ForeColor
{
    get { ... }
    set
    {
        if (_foreColor == value) return;
        _foreColor = value;

        // Force redraw to show new color in designer instantly
        if (DesignMode)
            Invalidate();
    }
}
```

[Invalidate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/598t492a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) requests a redraw.

[DesignMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component.designmode.aspx) returns whether this code is executed while in designer mode. So the code after the if-statement will **never** run for users.

Checking `DesignMode` is **optional** but it keeps the code clean and doesn't result in a redundant method call in runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
someGUIControl.Invalidate();
```

to make your control redraw.